# NativeScript + Angular project - How to change label text via pageloaded event

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to change the text of a `<Label/>` element when the when a `<Button/>` is tapped. I'm using the **pageLoaded** event to get the label from the **page.getViewById()** function. Buttons **tapAction()** function should change the text value of the Label.

This is the HTML code

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded">
 <StackLayout class="page">
   <Button text="Tap" class="btn btn-primary" (tap)="tapAction()"></Button>
   <Label id="lbl1" text="title 1" textWrap="true"></Label>
 </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

This is my pageLoaded function and the tapAction function in the TS file

```
import { EventData, Page } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/page/page';
import { Label } from "tns-core-modules/ui/label";

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  ......

  private label1: Label;

  public pageLoaded(args: EventData) {
      var page = <Page>args.object;
      this.label1 = <Label>page.getViewById("lbl1");
  }

  public tapAction() {
      this.label1.text = "Text changed.."
  }
}
```

When the button is taped **tapAction()** should be called and the text in Label should be changed. But nothing happens when the button is pressed.

Appreciate your help. Thank you!.

Comment: `loaded="pageLoaded"` should be `(loaded)="pageLoaded($event)"` .. you could also use `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: I would recommend instead to use Angular data binding

Comment: `<Label [text]="myString" ></Label>` and then in your component `this.myString = "some new string"`

Comment: Thanks @NickIliev I'll consider that.